# Unable to run python file in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

[click here to see the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLhlT.png)

My current file is variable_scope.py but no option to run this file is showing up although option to run older files are showing up , what to do ?

Comment: Don't link to screenshots of code; put code examples in the body of the question. Also, be clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what the results were.

Comment: @jdv its not a problem to do with code, its a pycharm related issue. Regarding the actual question stated by the OP, could you right-click on your file in the tabs things on the far right of the green arrow? There should be a run option.

Comment: @Octo My current file which i want to run (variable_scope.py) is not showing in the list how can i run it ?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below? Alt+Shift+10?

Comment: @Octo yes I tried but its still the same !

Answer (score 4):

First you have to set the project interpreter.when you opened pycharm go to the setting\project\project interpreter and set address of the python interpreter in your system.

After that you can run your code by selecting run at top menu and choosing Run... button. You can use the shortcut by pressing Alt+Shift+F10.

Comment: You can't run it yet!

Comment: No its not running!

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed your directory your interpreter (`python.exe`) will be lost as PyCharm will look for it in its previous path.

To fix this go to Settings or press `Ctrl+Alt+S` go to `Project` > `Project Interpreter` and from the Project Interpreter dropdown select `Show All` then from the list select the `python.exe` on its current path and press the `+` symbol on your right.